# Assembly compiled in older .NET version running in newer .NET version, will behavior change?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, winforms, .net-4.5

I have an assembly that is compiled with .NET 3.5.  I cannot recompile it in .NET 4.5 since it is used in other applications that are still running .NET 3.5.  When I use the assembly in my apps that are running .NET 4.5 will the assembly be treated as if it is running in .NET 4.5 instead of .NET 3.5?  I have a WinForms app and a WebForms app both in .NET 4.5.  If there are changes in behavior between .NET 3.5 and .NET 4.5, with the assembly return the 4.5 results?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually .Net frameworks are backward-compatible, so executing an assembly developed in .Net 3.5 shouldn't be a problem on 4.5.

You should see: [Version Compatibility in the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602939.aspx)

> The .NET Framework 4.5 is backward-compatible with applications that
>   were built with the .NET Framework versions 1.1, 2.0, 3.0, 3.5, and 4.
>   In other words, applications and components built with previous
>   versions of the .NET Framework will work on the .NET Framework 4.5.

But there could be problems as well like the one mentioned in the article :

> However, in practice, this compatibility can be broken by seemingly
>   inconsequential changes in the .NET Framework and changes in
>   programming techniques. For example, performance improvements in the
>   .NET Framework 4 can expose a race condition that did not occur on
>   earlier versions. Similarly, using a hard-coded path to .NET Framework
>   assemblies, performing an equality comparison with a particular
>   version of the .NET Framework, and getting the value of a private
>   field by using reflection are not backward-compatible practices. In
>   addition, each version of the .NET Framework includes bug fixes and
>   security-related changes that can affect the compatibility of some
>   applications and components.

The best way for you would be make sure your test cases pass after including dll from 3.5.